# How to integrate PayTM payment gateway with ANGULAR 9 app and how to handle the CALLBACK_URL

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, paytm

**I have integrated the payment gateway of PayTM in Angular 9 app**. But I don't know how to handle the **CALLBACK_URL**.
PayTM is sending the Form data using POST method. And I want to read the data in my component(CALLBACK_URL).
This is the incoming response of paytm that I can see in network chrome developer tool after success.

[image: 1]

and I want to read this response in my component.

Comment: The CALLBACK_URL should be an URL to your server. I'm sure what PayTM does is similar to PayPal's IPN. They send you a request to your callback URL with the informations of the payment, but as I said, this request has to be sent to a server, not to the client, so I can't see how could you manage that in Angular 9.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Merchant need to handle this from their backend not from front end Angular component. please confirm if it answers your query.